# firebase startAt + equalTo

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can you combine `startAt` and `equalTo` when there is entity like `timestamp_item`?

That is, lets say we have `1234567_itemA` and `1234567_itemB` and if i want to query only `itemA` data i'm still receiving both items.

Trying to filter it out with  `database().ref('items').orderByChild('timestamp_item').startAt('10000_itemA').limitToLast(10)`

**EDIT (fixed)**: had to change query into `(...).orderByChild('timestamp_item').startAt('10000_itemA').endAt('20000_itemA').limitToLast(10)`